Sharepoint 2019 on premise app successfully deployed but not available on sites
I have created App (SPFx customizer) it is successfully deployed on central admin app catalog, but not available on sites.
what is possible reason?

I think the app catalog must not be in yourcentral admin, but on an specific site collection, and when you deploy your app, who must check this solution should be available or all site collections

Please firstly make sure you have correctly added the app tp app catalog site.
Reference:  Manage the App Catalog in SharePoint Server,
and add the app from app catalog site:  Add apps for SharePoint to SharePoint sites
